# Unzip file in Microsoft PowerPoint slide

Tags: zip, powerpoint

I want to open the zip file in the Microsoft PowerPoint slide as shown below.

[image]

I got this error. Do you have any idea, how to fix this problem? Thanks

Error:

```
The server application, source file or item can't be found or returned an unknown error. You may need to reinstall the server application.
```

Comment: IT's off-topic here (powerpoint is not a programming language), but also rather unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the object, choose "Packager Shell Object Object" then "Activate ..."

That should open the zip file in whatever app is registered to handle ZIP files (by default, File Explorer).

Here, it opened *behind* PPT, so I needed to minimize PPT or Alt+Tab to the correct open app to see the contents of the zip. YMMV

Comment: I see. I try but the box that pop-up after we click activate, shows any value or any selection.

Comment: @dan I'm not clear one what you mean. Can you edit your original question and add a screenshot of what you see